# PHP date compare, todays date vs date stored in table as string

Tags: php, mysql, date

So I have a date stored in a table as a string (eg. 2-14-2014) I'm pretty sure that puts it in the format of m-j-Y, j because there are no leading zeros. How would I go about comparing this with todays date? I want to be able to have something that looks like:

```
if(event_date>today){
//send data to app
}else{
//delete item from table
}
```

Thank you in advance,

Tyler

Comment: Take a look at `strtotime`: http://php.net/strtotime

Comment: Have you made any attempt to do this at all?  Can you show more code context?

Comment: I did not know I had to parse the date so I was trying strtotime without parsing it first and it was just giving me a blank screen but now I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the strtotime function, but you'll need to format your date first:

```
$now = strtotime("now");
$dateArray = date_parse_from_format("n-j-Y", "2-12-2014");
$test = strtotime($dateArray['year'].'-'.$dateArray['month'].'-'.$dateArray['day']);
return $now > $test;
```

Comment: Thank you, I added that with Pattle answer and got exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert them both using strtotime , so suggested code would be :

```
$exp_date = "2014-01-16"; // or value from db
$todays_date = date("m-d-Y");

$today = strtotime($todays_date);
$expiration_date = strtotime($exp_date);

if ($expiration_date > $today) {
     // Do whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So first you want to convert the date into a UNIX Timestamp by using `strtotime`

```
$event_date = strtotime($date);
```

It sounds like you just want to check if the `$event_date` is in the future so you could do

```
if($event_date > time() {
    //Event is in the future
} else {
    //Event isn't in the future
}
```

Comment: Thank you that helped along with Brian Anderson.

Comment: I know this is off topic but how would I go about deleting an item from my table in //Event isn't in the future ?
I've tried $result1 = mysql_query("DELETE * FROM events WHERE pid = $pid_check"); but that is not working. I've also tried without the where, but still nothing